Equality involving non increasing rearrangements.
I am reading "Weakly Differentiable Functions" by William P. Ziemer, and I cannot prove an equality in a remark at page $28$ in the section on Lorentz spaces.
The equality involved the so called "non-increasing" rearrangement.
Let $f \in L^{1}(R)$ and define
$$
f^{*}(t) := \inf \{ s : \alpha_{f}(s) \leq t \},
$$
where $\alpha_{f}(s)$ is the measure of the super-level of $\vert f \vert$ relative to $s$; i.e,
$$ \alpha_{f}(s):= \vert \{ x : \vert f(x) \vert > s \} \vert.$$
Prove that
$$\int_{0}^{t} f^{*}(s)\ ds = t \cdot f^{*}(t) + \int_{f^{*}(t)}^{+\infty} \alpha_{f}(s)\ ds $$
We can use the fact that the "distributions functions" of $f$ and $f^{*}$ are the same
$$
\alpha_{f}(s) = \alpha_{f^{*}}(s).
$$
I am almost sure that this is the integration by part formula because $t*f^{*}(t)$ is a boundary term. Why $f^{*}(t)$ and $+\infty$ are the extrema of integration? The integral on the right feels like an integral from a change of variable $s \to f^{*}(s),$  and $f^{*}(t)$ is an extreme of integration because it is the smallest value for which $\alpha_{f}(s) \leq t.$
I know it's very imprecise, I think I am almost there, I just need the right hint!

I think that the formula can be justified by a Fubini-type argument. Note that the first integral is just the area of
$$
\{ (s,r) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid 0 \le s \le t, \, 0 \le r \le f^*(s) \}
$$
and we split this into (up to sets of measure zero)
$$
(0,t) \times (0, f^*(t))
\cup
\{ (s,r) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid 0 \le s \le t, \, f^*(t) \le r \le f^*(s) \}
.
$$
The second set can be written as (up to sets of measure zero)
$$
\{ (s,r) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid f^*(t) \le r < \infty, \, 0 \le s < \alpha_f(r) \}.
$$
Writing the areas as integrals gives your desired formula.
